# Obtaining rendered borders of a crooked svg-object

Tags: javascript, svg, vector-graphics, snap.svg

I need to know whether an svg-object is adjacent to another one or not. Therefore I need to get its borders.
Those objects can be a rect or a path. This is fairly easy when they are straight, but I don't know how to do this when they're curved or crooked.

An example of what I mean can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qvjs/26cm3h2a/) or a short example here:

```
<svg id="mysvg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 200 512 512">
   <path d="m 223.40414,282.21605 35.53211,-3.88909 0,-18.73833 -19.79899,-0.17678 c -5.83251,7.19542 -10.70707,15.0451 -15.73312,22.8042 z" id="pB"></path>
</svg>
```

If I use the Box corners, I create a `virtual` straight rectangular, which adjacent objects are not equal to the adjacents of the rendered object.
How can I do that?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#__svg__SVGPathElement__getPointAtLength

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Snap](http://snapsvg.io/) library offers some nice utilities for your problem. Your question does not define what "adjacent" should really mean. Here is a function that sets a threshold for the maximal distance between to paths:

```
var threshold = 1;

function isAdjacent (id1, id2) {
    var s = Snap("#mysvg");
    var first = s.select('#' + id1);
    var second = s.select('#' + id2);

    var len = first.getTotalLength(first);

    var p1, p2;
    for (var at = 0; at <= len; at += threshold) {
        p1 = first.getPointAtLength(at);
        if ( Snap.closestPoint(second, p1.x, p1.y).distance <= threshold) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r4vL42rg/)